# Windows XP VM not using allocated memory

Tags: windows-xp, memory, azure

I've got a Windows XP on a Medium Azure VM (2 cores, 3.5 GB memory). However, Windows only shows 512 MB of physical memory. I understand there are limits on a 32-bit OS, but it should be much higher than 512 MB. How can I get Windows to use more memory?

Comment: How much memory does show the BIOS?

Comment: I don't think you can see the BIOS on a VM in the cloud. If it's possible, please let me know how. Thanks!

Comment: Ok, I did not know that Azure is a cloud VM service. :) There must be some sort of BIOS but it is possible that it is not accessible or that it is so streamlined that it does not show any output at all.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It appears that your VM is configured using the best practices for Hyper-V, which is what Azure runs on.  Hyper-V utilizes dynamic memory allocation to allow more VMs to run on a given host and the recommended minimum for Windows XP is 512MB.  However, Windows XP doesn't support dynamic memory, so it is stuck with the amount of memory allocated in the minimum memory setting.  You should contact their customer support and either have them adjust the minimum memory setting to 3.5GB, or change to the Extra Small Instance.